# ExtJS 4 MVC desktop - how to create/open a module programmatically

Tags: extjs4, extjs-mvc

I have a working web desktop app very similar to the out-of-the-box ExtJS desktop example, where there are a number of icons, which, when clicked, spawn a window.

I am trying to figure out how to do the same thing programmatically:

```
var x = Ext.create('MyApp.view.users.Module')
x.launcher.handler();
```

this calls the createWindow() function, first line of which is:

```
var b = this.app.getDesktop();
```

This line bombs:

*Cannot call method 'getDesktop' of undefined*

which obviously means that "this" doesn't have "app" on it.

I am an ExtJS novice, and don't know how to tie the module to the app, or how to grab the module properly the way clicking the icon does. Any help would be appreciated.

Module code:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.users.Module', {

requires:                     ["Ext.tab.Panel"],
alias:                        'widget.usersmodule',
extend:                       'Ext.ux.desktop.Module',
id:                           'users-module-win',
itemId:                       'usersmodule',

init:                          function(){
    this.launcher = {
        handler:               this.createWindow,
        iconCls:              'icon-users',
        scope:                 this,
        text:                 'Users',
        windowId:             'users-module-win'
    }
},

...

createWindow:                    function(){
    var b = this.app.getDesktop();
    var a = b.getWindow('users-module-win');

    ...

    a.show();
    return a
},

...
```

});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I figured out one way to resolve this issue.

When I create my desktop app as part of application creation, I set global variable to the result of that action:

```
var _myDesktopApp;

Ext.application({

appFolder:'MyApp',

controllers:[
  ....
],

name:'MyApp',

launch:function () {

        Ext.Loader.setPath({
            ....
        });

        Ext.require('MyDesktop.App');
        Ext.require('Ext.tab.*');

        Ext.onReady(function () {
            _myDesktopApp = Ext.create('MyDesktop.App');
        });
    };
}
```

});

Then in my desktop file, I can get a specific module and open it with some initial size settings:

```
Ext.define("MyDesktop.App", {
extend:                     "Ext.ux.desktop.App",
requires:                    [
    "Ext.window.MessageBox",
    "Ext.ux.desktop.ShortcutModel",

    "MyApp.view.prospects.Module",        
    "MyApp.view.users.Module"
],
init:                        function () {
    this.callParent();

    var prospects_width = 700;
    var prospects_height = 500;
    var prospects_x = 0;
    var prospects_y = 0;
    _myDesktopApp.getModule('prospects-module-window').createWindow(prospects_width, prospects_height, prospects_x, prospects_y);

    var users_width = 700;
    var users_height = 500;
    var users_x = 700;
    var users_y = 0;
    _myDesktopApp.getModule('users-module-window').createWindow(users_width, users_height, users_x, users_y);
},

....
```

This code opens 2 module windows on load, and places them on the desktop side by side.

Answer (score 0):

You have a scoping issues going on here. Try changing init method to initComponent.

Debug your app using Firefox with Firebug. Place breakpoint on var b =... line and see what variables are in scope.